# Cannot slider jQuery UI slider

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, jquery-ui

I have a weird bug on my jquery UI slider, using the jquery UI rails gem. CSS and js are loading, but for some reason, it gets displayed as a number input.

[image: Actual slider]

JS is working fine (using $('.slider').slider() generates the right input )
CSS is loading as it should

What am I missing ?

If anything, here's the rails helper :

```
<%= f.number_field :deposit_percentage, class: "slider" %>
```

Comment: Sam happen when you change `f.number_field` to `f.input` ?

Comment: Nope, I get a standard input when changing it to f.input (no css at all, no slider either)

Comment: Can you add the resulting HTML to your post? I suspect there is some styling happening or something is missing in the result.